# Unity 2D Canvas Scaler

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working in Unity, and something stuck in my mind. What is the difference between the UI Scale Mode options in the section of the canvas scaler component, can anyone explain it?

There are 3 UI Scale Mode options.  Which of these 3 options should I use and what do they do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Corrected the wording for clarity.  Unity is a great platform.  Hope you get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check here for a more detailed explanation of each field: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-CanvasScaler.html

But basically:

**Constant Pixel Size:** means the UI elements will have the same pixel size always, no matter what size of screen do you have. So if you have a 100px X 100px button on your screen at 1920x1080 it will fill just a small portion of your screen, but if your screen resolution changes to 200x200 for example, than the button will be giant and fill a much bigger part of the screen now.

**Scale With Screen Size:** means exactly what it says, the UI will scale according to the screen size, so if you work and create your UI on a 960x540 screen and then change to 1920x1080 for example, your UI will scale, and in this case make the UI 2 times bigger because the screen is now 2 times bigger, so the aspect of the button will appear the same in all resolutions.

**Constant Physical Size:** uses DPI instead of pixels. DPI means "dots (pixels) per inch", meaning you it doesn't matter what the size of your screen is, the amount of pixels you define the UI will cover will remain the same, so for example if you have a 1920x1080 screen, and a 200x100 button, the button will be small on the screen, but if you play the game in a cellphone with lower resolution, 1280x720 for example, the button will remain with the same pixel density, 200x100, but since the screen has less pixels now the button will appear bigger, but in reality the resolution of the button in both cases remains the same.

But all of them also change the way anchors will work on your UI. The best way to know what you should use and what each one does is by testing yourself.

You can read more here as well for more information: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html